# Slider showing the right content but not leading to the right permalink

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a custom Wordpress theme which is Goblog theme, in which a slider is included (it's not a plugin). The slider worked fine untile one day it stoped working correctly. The only change I could have done about the slider was editing the CSS to add more height, which, I think, isn't the cause of this issue.

Basically everything works great on the slider, unless that the permalinks does not match with the content, and when clicked on, it redirects to another article.

Here is the php for the slider :

```
<?php if($bpxl_goblog_options['bpxl_home_slider'] == '1') { ?>
        <div class="featuredslider flexslider loading">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                    $slider_cat = '';
                    if(!empty($bpxl_goblog_options['bpxl_home_slider_cat'])) {
                        $slider_cats = $bpxl_goblog_options['bpxl_home_slider_cat'];
                        $slider_cat = implode(",", $slider_cats);
                    }
                    $slider_query = new WP_Query("cat=".$slider_cat."&orderby=date&order=DESC&showposts=3");
                ?>
                <?php if($slider_query->have_posts()) : while ($slider_query->have_posts()) : $slider_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="featured-thumbnail featured-widgetslider">
                            <?php
                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    the_post_thumbnail('featured');
                                } else {
                                    echo '<img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/770x360.png" />';
                                }
                            ?>
                            <div class="post-inner textcenter">
                                <header>
                                    <h2 class="title title22">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="slider-meta" style="display:none;"><span><?php _e('Ecrit par'); ?></span> <?php the_author(); ?></div>
                                </header><!--.header-->
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

The ouput HTML of the current slider (without editing) :

```
<div class="featuredslider flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                                                            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;" class="">
                        <a href="http://db-super.fr/episode-6-vostfr-dragon-ball-super/" title="Dragon Ball Super : Episode 6 VOSTFR" class="featured-thumbnail featured-widgetslider">
                            <img width="770" height="360" src="http://db-super.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/DBSUPER-Episode-6-screen-6-770x360.jpg?7ac485" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="Beerus" draggable="false">                               <div class="post-inner textcenter">
                                <header>
                                    <h2 class="title title22">
                                        Title                                       </h2>
                                    <div class="slider-meta" style="display:none;"><span>Ecrit par</span></div>
                                </header><!--.header-->
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;" class="">
                        <a href="http://db-super.fr/episode-5-vostfr-dragonball-super/" title="Dragon Ball Super : Episode 5 VOSTFR" class="featured-thumbnail featured-widgetslider">
                            <img width="770" height="360" src="http://db-super.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/dbsuper-episode-5-770x360.jpg?7ac485" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="dbsuper episode 5" draggable="false">                             <div class="post-inner textcenter">
                                <header>
                                    <h2 class="title title22">
                                        Title</h2>
                                    <div class="slider-meta" style="display:none;"><span>Ecrit par</span></div>
                                </header><!--.header-->
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                            <li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;" class="flex-active-slide">
                        <a href="http://db-super.fr/marathon-dragonball-z-cinema-grand-rex/" title="Marathon Dragon Ball Z au cinéma Le Grand Rex" class="featured-thumbnail featured-widgetslider">
                            <img width="770" height="360" src="http://db-super.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/fukkatu-770x360.jpg?7ac485" class="attachment-featured wp-post-image" alt="fukkatu" draggable="false">                             <div class="post-inner textcenter">
                                <header>
                                    <h2 class="title title22">
                                        Title</h2>
                                    <div class="slider-meta" style="display:none;"><span>Ecrit par</span></div>
                                </header><!--.header-->
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                                        </ul>
        <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a class="">1</a></li><li><a class="">2</a></li><li><a class="flex-active">3</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li></ul></div>
```

I thought this might be a permalink issue, so I reloaded them. Also thinking it could be a cache issue I tried to desactivate some plugins that could interacts with the slider.
That's why I finally thought this issue came from the php code itself, unfortunately I didn't figured out where was the issue.

Any ideas of what is causing this problem ?

Edit : you can watch the slider here db-super .fr
Edit 2 : This issue is still not solved and i'm still looking for the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Replace following line:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="featured-thumbnail featured-widgetslider">
```

with this one:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="featured-thumbnail featured-widgetslider">
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately it did not fix the issue. I don't understand why the ouput html of the slider shows the correct URL but not the slider itself.

Comment: I just have checked it on my PC and its working perfectly now, please clear your browser cache and reload the page.

Comment: Are you sure it redirects to the right URLs ? I cleared my cache using Chrome option, another full clean with CCleaner, cleared all caches with W3TC, tried on differents browsers, PCs (some never visited the site before). I still get the wrongs URLs redirection.

Comment: Please be online, I have checked it on Firefox and yes its working perfectly, let me check it on chrome

Comment: I just checked it on Chrome, and its working well on it too.

Comment: have you checked it using incognito ( private ) mode.

Comment: I just tried it on Chrome private mode, it's the same. I don't understand. But I guess if you can assure me that it's working, that'll do it. Still strange though.

Comment: if you like i can show you through skype screen sharing